# Unable to get 3.5 inch touchscreen to work with Pi 3B

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, noobs

I am unable to get my Pi 3B to work with a 3.5in RPI Touchscreen LCD v3.0. I have NOOBS and the Raspbain OS Image downloaded to my micro SD Card. All it does when I set it up is turn white. What is the problem?

Comment: can you attach a photo of how you have it setup? and maybe include a link to where you bought the screen? also does the pi work when connected to a monitor?

Comment: I had the same problem, except it was with a TFT, not an LCD. Can you attach a picture of the **back** of the screen? PS. I know this isn't an answer, but I can't comment unless I have 50 rep.... (where's the logic SE?)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what LCD screen you have, the following may work. First check if the display looks like the [picture here](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.2inch_RPi_LCD_(B)). There are many cheap clones of these available on Chinese sites. If it looks similar, first download the correct driver:

For 2016-May-10-raspbian-jessie or later:

```
wget http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/2/24/LCD-show-160520.tar.gz
```

For older jessie versions:

```
wget http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/3/37/LCD-show-151102.tar.gz
```

After downloading do the following:

```
tar xvf LCD-show-160520.tar.gz
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./LCD35-show
```

It will reboot and if you are lucky you might have a working display.